# docker how to run a dangling image

Tags: docker

imagine I have build an image locally and it has no name.

I want to run that image.

So if for instance I have built this:

```
$ docker images -f dangling=true
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
<none>       <none>    c53eebebe11c   About a minute ago   75.2MB
<none>       <none>    c53eebebe11c   About a minute ago   74.9MB
```

how would I run the dangling image without a tag?

I tried `docker run --rm -it c53eebebe11c bash` but that would fail with the message:

```
Unable to find image 'c53eebebe11c:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/c53eebebe11c:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So the question is, how to run a dangling docker image?

Comment: I may add I am using the following version of docker on my macbook

`$ docker --version
Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a`

Answer (score 0):

While I dont know how to run the image directly, I found this workaround:

You can provide a tag for the dangling image and then run the tagged image:

```
docker tag my_tag_name c53eebebe11c
docker run --rm -it my_tag_name bash
```